# Difference between .is and .filter in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-filter

Can I ask what the function is of `.is` and `.filter` in jQuery, and what is their difference?

Comment: google is your friend http://docs.jquery.com/Is http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.is()` returns true if at least one of the elements you're calling it on matches the selector.

`.filter()` returns only those elements from the set you're calling it on which match the selector

The proper definitions and examples can be found at:
[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Hope that helps..?